# Kendo UI template click binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Using a kendo template, I am trying to create a button that will be bound to an ajax call, currently I have a very simple way to do it, I use a link. What I would like to do now is to have the id of the element that was clicked available inside the function.

```
requestEnd: function(e) {
  var response = e.response;
  var type = e.type;

  var cardTemplate = kendo.template($("#cardTemplate").html());
  var data = response;

  var cardResult = cardTemplate(data);
  $("#panels").html(cardResult);

  kendo.bind($("#panels"), viewModel);

  $(".wf-card-operations").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().find('.wf-card-id').attr('id');
    console.log("deleteProcessInstance " + id);
  });
}
```

Currently I am binding events upon a requestEnd, what I would like to do is to have the id binded to a function

```
deleteProcessInstance : function(e){
  console.log("deleteProcessInstance "+id); //How do I get the id?
}
```

template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="cardTemplate">
# for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{ #
    <li>
        <div class="k-block">
            <div class="wf-card-header">
                <span class="wf-card-name"> #= data[i].name # </span><br/>
            </div>

            <div class="wf-card-footer">
                <span id="#: data[i].id #" class="wf-card-id"> #= data[i].id # </span><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="wf-card-operations">
                <div class="wf-start" data-bind="click:startProcess">Start</div>
                <div class="wf-download">Download</div>
                <div class="wf-delete" data-bind="click:deleteProcessInstance ">Delete</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
# } #
```

Comment: Addded template code, its a simple click data-binding each card has a section to start, download or delete... my problem is to have the id inside of the binding functions

Comment: why not using custom data attr like <div class="wf-delete" data-id="#: data[i].id #".. and then var id = $(e.target).data("id")

Comment: I would like to be able to use data[i],id only one for the three methods, but if there is no better way, ill probably do it that way.